# How to use bean arraylist into the another bean with hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I want to use a bean arraylist into the another bean as a field. And I got "**mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property"** error.

I have two class 1. Logs 2. Log and all Logs element includes one more than a Log. log.executionid can be multiple records, but all logs.executionid must be different

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_logs")
public class Logs {

@Id
@Column(name = "executionid")
private String executionId;

@Column(name = "sentdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date sendDate;

@Column(name = "exceptionmessage")
private String exceptionMessage;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "executionid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Log> loglist;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "t_log")
public class Log {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "executionid")
private String executionId;

@Column(name = "startdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "enddate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is correct answer thanks to @Guilherme Ribeiro Developer

Logs table;

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "logs", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Log> loglist;
```

Log table;

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "executionid")
    private Logs logs;
```

Answer (score 0):

mappedBy = "executionid" is wrong.

this field must to refer to a "property". That's what the error says.

It must be mappedBy = "executionId" , the field class name instead of the column name.

Comment: i changed it by your advice. and here is another error. could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKQHMEB54EQ0BQE9CBKD6A2KHND: PUBLIC.T_LOG FOREIGN KEY(EXECUTIONID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.T_LOGS(EXECUTIONID) ('39c45fc9-9a29-48d0-9bf8-0c91a65a5346')";

Comment: Good!! Now you must do this work at the database level.  Of course, the executionid column must be a foreign key for the related table.

Comment: You could try to do an analogy to Department vs Employee relation. 
On database level:  One Department must have one ore more Employees
                                One Employee must be in just one Department.

Jpa Level:   Department class ->  @OneToMany List<Employee>

Comment: my database created by hibernate automatically. I droped db after that it was recreated, but no any changes.

Comment: but in my project algorithm log must not be include any logs.

Comment: It's because the supposed id of Log class is "id" instead of "executionId". The database driver couldn't create the FK because it's not a PK.

Comment: So sory but i couldn't understand.

Comment: I want to try this http://www.javatpoint.com/list-one-to-many but via annotations

Comment: Other thing, you mapped by field must be an entity too.

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-association-annotations-example

Comment: Look at this link. Explains very well. But I've answered your first error anyway lol!